# Test onBlur event in React component using Jest/Enzyme not firing

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, onblur

I am testing the onBlur event in the Textbox(a child component inside BasePartnerRegistrationForm that's connected to redux store).  I tried all means in SOF posts but the console always shows below.  Is it really the onBlur event not firing? How can I debug this to find out what is causing the root problem? Is there other things that possibly not letting me testing the onBlur...

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

```
class BasePartnerRegistrationForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ages: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createExperiences();
  }

  createExperiences() {
    let experiences = [
      { value: '', text: 'First time order?' },
      { value: 'yes', text: 'Yes' },
      { value: 'no', text: 'No' },
      { value: 'not sure', text: "I'm not sure" },
    ];
    this.setState({ experiences: experiences });
  }

  checkUserByEmail(elemName, value) {
    getUserByEmail(value)
      .then((results) => {
        let showLoginNote = true;
        let notifications = document.getElementsByClassName('message');

        __forEach(notifications, (message) => {
          if (__startsWith(message.textContent, 'It looks like you have an account')) {
            showLoginNote = false;
            return false;
          }
        });

        if (!__isEmpty(results) && showLoginNote) {
          notify('info', 'It looks like you have an account. Click here to log in.', 0, () => {
            this.props.history.push('/login');
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div data-type="email" className="textbox-wrapper">
          <Textbox
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email Address"
            name="register-email"
            onChange={this.setEmail}
            onBlur={this.checkUserByEmail}
            defaultValue={this.state.email}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { saveEmail };

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(BasePartnerRegistrationForm);
```

my test case:

```
it('calls checkUserByEmail when the Textbox for email is onBlur', () => {
    const checkUserByEmailSpy = jest.spyOn(BasePartnerRegistrationForm.WrappedComponent.prototype, 'checkUserByEmail');

    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BasePartnerRegistrationForm {...baseProps} />
      </Provider>
    );
    const onBlurEvent = wrapper.find('Textbox').at(0);
    
    onBlurEvent.simulate('blur', { target: { name: 'register-email' } });
    
    expect(checkUserByEmailSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```